# Why aren't these floating point values equal to each other in Sass?

Tags: sass

I'm calculating different `line-height`s within a Sass mixin to ensure that different elements adhere to a vertical rhythm. My `$vertical-rhythm-base` is currently `8px`.

Some browsers (at least Chrome) seem to floor a value of `1.33333` and use `23px` instead of the desired `24px` I had in mind. So I tried to correct that value within my mixin:

```
$vertical-rhythm-base: 8px

=calculateLineHeight($itemFontSize)
  $lineHeightBase: $vertical-rhythm-base * 3
  $itemLineHeight: (ceil($itemFontSize/$lineHeightBase)*$lineHeightBase)/$itemFontSize
  // fix miscalculation for this value since browsers resort to 23px
  // instead of 24px in the current setup.
  @if $itemLineHeight == 1.33333
    $itemLineHeight: 1.3334

  line-height: $itemLineHeight

.someElement
  +calculateLinHeight(18px)
  font-size: 18px
```

This doesn't seem to work since the items that should get a `line-height: 1.33334` still get `line-height: 1.33333`.

I don't get what is going wrong here. Changing the `@if` to use `=` instead of `==` results in assigning `line-height: 1.33334` to everything instead of calculating it correctly.

Comment: There's not enough information here to reproduce the problem.  You have uninitalized variables, and you're not showing how you're calling the mixin to even get that value.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I added some more context (although the question was already answered, better document this right :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass doesn't perform rounding until *after* the comparisons are already done and it is time to generate the output.  Your variable still contains a repeating decimal, even if it looks like it doesn't. You must compare repeating values to repeating values if you're checking for equality:

```
$foo: 4 / 3;

@debug $foo == 1.33333; // false
@debug $foo == 4 / 3;   // true
```

Note that if Sass performed rounding at comparison time rather than after, your if-statement would only evaluate to true when using the default precision setting of 5 (there are a number of Sass libraries that require higher precision settings than that, I ran the above code with a precision of 10).  Also note that the default precision for Sass has changed once before and is likely to change again in the future.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer and the explanation. Learned a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

1,33333 is repetend. Try "==(4/3)"

Comment: Wow, that was almost too easy :D Thank you so much!